# Why does == work and = does not in an if statement?

Tags: c++, operators

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.at(i) = n) {
    cout << "True";
        return 0;
      }}
```

I was wondering why this would not work I understand that tou should use `list.at(i) == n`.
However i thought that a single = means assigning, and a double == means equal to. I understand it is different but wouldn't using only one = still be correct when using it in an if statement?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, and `==` is the comparison operator. The `if (list[at(i) = n)` tries to assign `n` to `list.at(i)` and evaluate the result, which clearly won't work. Learn the difference between comparison and assignment.

Comment: They do both *work*, in the sense that, if they compile without a diagnosable error, they will each produce some specified behaviour.   The difference is that they produce *different* behaviours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not necessarily be correct. When you use an assignment expression as a boolean for integers, it will return `true` if the integer is not zero, and it will return `false` if the integer is zero.

Suppose our list looks like this: `1, 2, 0, 5`. Now, suppose we have this if-statement:

```cpp
if (list.at(0) = 1) {
    cout << "True";
}
```

Since the 1 in `list.at(0) = 1` is not 0, the if-condition will be satisfied. If we used `==`, it would be satisfied since the first value is indeed 1.

Now let's suppose we have this if-statement:

```cpp
if (list.at(1) = 3) {
    cout << "True";
}
```

The `"True"` would be printed because 3 is not equal to 0. However, if we replaced `=` with `==`, the `"True"` would not be printed since the second value is not 3.

Let's look at one last example.

```cpp
if (list.at(2) = 0) {
    cout << "True";
}
```

This would not print out `"True"` since we are assigning `list.at(2)` to 0. However, if we replaced the `=` with `==`, the `"True"` would be printed since the third value in the list is actually 0.

This shows that `=` cannot be used as `==`.

P.S. And, if you wanted to use the list later, your list would be modified into a different list.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (condition) {
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition is true
}
```

Here is your code list.at(i) = n is an assignment and not a condition. Seeing your code I can say that you want to check if any value in the list is equal to n or not if it is then you want to print True.
So to do this you have to use a condition if(list.at(i)==n).
For more information read about condition statements, comparison operators, and assignment operators.

Comment: This does not really answer the actual question that was asked. Although what you wrote is generally true, we generally try to answer the actual questions that are asked, instead of providing a related, but an irrelevant explanation fo something else. Can you reread the question, and answer what's asked, directly?